# How to exclude path based on regex in check_disk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, nagios

If I do

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -r '/drop-zone/*'
```

when it only checks paths which matches the regex. I would like the opposite. The [manpage](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_disk.html) seams to suggest `-I`, but I don't understand how to use it.

**Question**

How do I make `check_disk` check all paths except those that match a regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read manpage carefully, you can use `-A` to check all path, then use `-I` to ignore path that match regex:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -A -I '/drop-zone/*'
```

This will check all path exclude path that match '/drop-zone/*'.

Comment: `/drop-zone/*` is not a regex.